# Moving forward and backward with multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, activity-finish

I have 4 activities(ActivityA, ActivityB, ActivityC, ActivityD).

I Moved from ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC -> ActivityD.

Now I want to know what I do in fallowing 2 conditions.

1. When go to ActivityB from ActivityD by skip ActivityC
2. When go to ActivityA from ActivityD by skip ActivityB & ActivityC

**Note:** Here i could not want to call **finishaffinity** method to finish all activity and launch desired Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your activity Activity A and Activity B in manifest with the SingleTask launch mode.

The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one. It will also clear all the activities which are over that Activity. For eg- If you start Activity B from Activity D, then initially your stack would be A->B->C->D which will then be changed to A->B.

[Check this out for the complete official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode)

Hope it helps.